# SQL database with Phorum

Tags: php, sql-server, forums

I was just exploring Phorum for my website.  I already have a separate log in system associated with the main website, which I was hoping to be able to carry over to Phorum, so people don't have to sign up twice.

I saw the way to hook in a SQL database through include/db/config.php, but there seems to be no good documentation on what's going to be carried in the table I set it to.  Will is just be username/password?

Assuming it is, is there a way I can have it so if you signed in on my site, you don't have to re sign in for phorum?  Even just a link pointing in the right direction would be outstanding.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify your site to use the Phorum database and user registration system. This would be the best way to do it. You could write a small SQL import script for your existing users and then just link to the phorum rego page from your site.

If you are not keen on taking this approach, you'd need to update both user tables (yours and phorums) when data was changed / inserted. Also you'd both need to use the same cookie.

Does that help?

Comment: Seems obvious, but I hadn't thought to just use theirs.  I really shouldn't program at 1 in the morning

Comment: Thats the best time to program. More challenging. :)